# Using forEach Loop Generating prime number in Javascript between 1 to 50

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, function

Here's my code but my answer is not that which i want..

**Please Check This and give me a solution to get prime number using Foreach Loop b/w 1-50**

Thanks In Advance :)

```
function isPrime(num) {
    for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
        if ( num % i === 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
    var txt = "";
    function shown(n) {
        var arr = [2];
        arr.forEach(myFunction);

document.getElementById("foreach").innerHTML = txt;
// document.getElementById('forLoop').innerHTML = arr; // use arr result on your own
}
function myFunction(arr, index, array) {

var i;
var arr = [2];

if ( isPrime(i) ) {
    arr.push(i);
      }
  txt += arr + "<br>"; 
}

shown(50);
```

Comment: Might try here first: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What errors are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Comment: I think you need to first logically break down your problem into small steps. Then, when you try solving the steps one-by-one, you can come up with more specific problem with, maybe, one specific step. And with that specific problem, you can probably find solution online already.

Comment: @twisty i just wants a prime numbers through forEach Loop

Comment: @Gerard No Dear, i want to use forEach loop not for Loop

Comment: @AbdullahRao a `.forEach()` loop on what array?

Comment: @Twisty i have explained before in my question.. array is between 1 to 50 numbers

Comment: @AbdullahRao your example does not show this. you have an array with a single element: `[2]`.

Comment: but in shown(50) it shows that array starts with 2 and ends on 50

Comment: @AbdullahRao You just pasted your whole code here. There are many logical steps in it that you can verify one-by-one. Thay way you'd be able to submit a more specific question than this "I don't know how to do the whole thing" type question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think so this is the correct answer which i deserve..
It is code lover short and aggressive

```
function primes(limit)
{
  var prime=[], i=1;
  while (++i < limit+1) prime.reduce((a,c)=>(i%c)*a,1) && prime.push(i);
  prime.unshift(2);
  return prime;
}
[50].forEach(n=>document.getElementById('foreach').innerHTML=(`${primes(n)}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a too-advanced answer for a homework of this level, but technically it follows the rules (use Array.forEach) and it works.

The `primes()` generates new primes based on previous primes. So it won't test the reminder of all integers, thus more effecient. There are several arrow function uses, too, to keep things short. If you indeed use this answer, please try to read the relevant documentations and learn:

- [Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)
- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Seriously, try to think step-by-step. That's how you learn anything.

```js
function* primes() {
  const previous = [];

  for (let i = 2; true; i++) {
    let isPrime = true;
    for (let p of previous) {
      if (i % p === 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
      previous.push(i);
      yield i;
    }
  }
}

function* takeUntil(cb, iter) {
  for (let val of iter) {
    if (cb(val)) {
      return;
    }
    yield val;
  }
}

function showArrayIn(arr, container) {
  arr.forEach(p => container.innerHTML += `${p},<br/>`); // technically, we used Array.forEach.
}

showArrayIn(
  // get the prime number array declarativly 
  Array.from(takeUntil(n => n >= 50, primes())),
  // show in the container specified
  document.getElementById("results")
);
```

```html
Primes:
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function primeFactorsTo(max)
{
    var store  = [], i, j, primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) 
    {
        if (!store [i]) 
          {
            primes.push(i);
            for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) 
            {
                store[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

console.log(primeFactorsTo(5));

console.log(primeFactorsTo(15));
```

Comment: See my question above

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  if (num === 1) {
    return false;
  } else if (num === 2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    for (var x = 2; x < num; x++) {
      if (num % x === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

function shown(n) {
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  list.slice().reverse().forEach(function(n, k, o) {
    if (!isPrime(n)) {
      list.splice(o.length - 1 - k, 1);
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = list;
}

shown(50);
```

```html
Prime: <p id="show"></p>
```

Comment: Please use ForEach Loop in this program,

Comment: @AbdullahRao updated.

Comment: Thanks Dear, But 2 is also a prime number

Comment: This is just showing odd numbers. Not prime numbers.

Comment: Yes it showing me odd numbers these are are not prime numbers